# A question regarding the proof of "if $H'$ is a normal sub-group of $G'$, $f^{-1}(H')$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ ($f$ being a homomorphism)"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups

The theorem I'm studying is:

> Let $f: (G ,.) \rightarrow (G',.)$ be a group homomorphism, and $H'$ a normal subgroup of $G'$. In that case: $H= f^{-1}(H') $ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

**PROOF** [from Reversat&Bigonnet , *Algèbre pour la licence* (Undergraduate abstract algebra), 1997, p. 34]

Note: my question only deals with the ***last argument*** of the proof, on the ***last line***.

(1) By a previous theorem, we know that the reciprocal image of a subgroup under a group homomorphism is a group. So, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

(2) We also know, as a general rule, that the proposition: $\space \space H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, is equivalent to: $\space \space \forall g_ {\in G}, gHg^{-1} \subseteq H\space \space $.

$\space \space \space$ So, all we have to prove is that,

- for all $g_{\in G}$ and all $\overline {g}_{\in f^{-1}(H')} , g\overline {g}g^{-1}\in f^{-1}(H')$

which amounts to proving that

- **$f(g\overline {g}g^{-1}) \in H'$**.

$\space \space \space$ Now,

$$f(g\overline {g}g^{-1})= f(g) f(\overline {g}) f(g^{-1})$$

**Since $f(\overline {g})$ belongs to $H'$, so does $f(g\overline {g}g^{-1})$.**

If we already  knew (from elsewhere)  that $f(g)$ belongs to $H'$ I would see how the argument: $f(\overline {g})\in H'$ leads to the desired conclusion. (Indeed: $H'$ is closed under inverses and under the binary operation of $G'$).

> ***But how can  this argument $f(\overline {g})\in H'$ do the job by itself?***

---

Thanks to the hint given by @MarkBennet, I explain the last stept of the proof for potential readers meeting the same difficulty as I did :

$f(g\overline {g}g^{-1})$

$= f(g) f(\overline {g}) f(g^{-1})$ ( because $f$ is a homomorphism)

$= f(g) f(\overline {g}) f(g)^{-1}$ ( because, the image of the inverse by a homomorphism is the inverse of the image)

But,here, we can apply the general rule mentionned above (see point (2) ) ,because  $H'$ is a normal subgroup of $G'$ and because ( by definition )$f(\overline {g}) \in H'$ . Applying this rule yields :

$$f(g) f(\overline {g}) f(g)^{-1}\in H'$$

which implies that

$$f(g\overline {g}g^{-1})\in H' $$

and finally that

$$g\overline {g}g^{-1}\in f^{-1} (H')$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that under $f$, because it is a homomorphism, $f(g)$ and $f(g^{-1})$ are inverses in $G'$. Then use that $H'$ is normal in $G'$.

Comment: I see ! Thanks for this hint!